# ionic - Using arguments with navCtrl.push()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mobile, ionic-framework

I am calling a method from home.html

```
(click)="openPage(EventsPage)"
```

I am aware if I just use this method

```
openPage() {
  this.navCtrl.push(EventsPage)
}
```

in home.ts it will work.

Basically I want to take in a different argument depending on whats clicked but only use one method to navigate to the selected page e.g.

```
(click)="openPage(EventsPage)"
(click)="openPage(TimetablePage)"

openPage(page) { 
  this.navCtrl.push(page)
}
```

Do I need to just use a switch statement or ifs? I was hoping I could keep it to just the one or two lines.

Any suggestions or advice appreciated thanks.

Comment: Youre question is peculiar. If you have multiple buttons, the indicated Setup will work

Comment: I'd suggest going with lazy loading and just passing the page (component) string reference on to your openPage(page) function.

Comment: user7722867 I thought the same thing but apparently that is not the case 

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems like a project that you are just starting with or fiddling with, this is what I'd suggest.

when you create any new pages, create page.module.ts along with them.

a typical page.module.ts would look like this

```
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {YourPage} from './your-page.ts';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [YourPage],
    imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(YourPage)]
})
export class YourPageModule{}
```

this is how your-page.ts would look like

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage} from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
   selector: 'your-page',
   templateUrl: 'your-page.html'
})
export class YourPage{}
```

when you have all of this setup, you can just send 'YourPage' string to the openPage(page) function to navigate to YourPage component.

Pushing a string instead of an imported page instance via ionics `NavController` also enables lazy-loading (the js-bundle for page is fetched when needed, not all at once at startup). This can significantly improve your startup-time if you have an app with many pages. I also suggest reading the IonicPage [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/), they are quite useful when dealing with navigation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just heading into work now but I'll give your soloution a try first thing tomorrow. Thanks for your time I'll keep you updated.